# C/C++ Large number calculation

Tags: c++, c, math, numbers, modulo

I'm trying to compute the following number in a C program :

```
result = (3 * pow(2,500000000) - 2 ) % 1000000000
```

The power of 2 is way to large to be handled properly => I'm under the impression I could split the calculation in many steps using the modulo to reduce the result size. Does someone has a strategy for doing so ? Any other idea ?

Thanx in advance

Manu

Comment: I asked this calc to wolframalpha.com and still waiting the answer

Answer (score 9):

The simplest method is exponentiation by repeated squaring reducing by the modulus in each step.

```
unsigned long long mod_pow(unsigned long long base, unsigned long long exponent, unsigned long long modulus)
{
    if (exponent == 0) return 1;
    unsigned long long aux = 1;
    while(exponent > 1) {
        if (exponent % 2 != 0) {
            aux *= base;
            aux %= modulus;
        }
        base *= base;
        base %= modulus;
        exponent /= 2;
    }
    return (base*aux) % modulus;
}
```

You can then use that to compute

```
result = (3*mod_pow(2,500000000,1000000000) - 2) % 1000000000;
```

The function supposes that the square of the modulus does not exceed the 64-bit range. For larger moduli, things are more complicated.

Comment: (exponent % 2 != 0) === (exponent & 1) ?

Comment: Yes, both test whether the exponent is odd, which in a pure binary representation is the case if and only if the least significant bit is set.

Comment: thanx for the quick reply. It works real fine and is actually pretty fast !

Comment: is one better (faster) than the other? Or preferred stylistically?

Comment: @Will Stylistically, one should write what one means (unfortunately, I tend to think in the bit patterns, so I tend to mean `& 1` and `>> 1` where others mean `% 2` and `/ 2`). On most machines the bit operations are faster than the division operations, but most C compilers recognise the pattern and optimise accordingly. However, the GHC developers have not yet come to implement all these low-level optimisations, so in Haskell it's something I **have** to do myself (for the time being).

Comment: This sort of problem is typically posed as homework or a contest problem. Giving a complete solution may interfere with learning or give a competitor an undeserved advantage.

Comment: Right, @Eric, didn't think of that. I'll try to remember.