# Using pow() for large number

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am trying to solve a problem, a part of which requires me to calculate (2^n)%1000000007 , where n<=10^9. But my following code gives me output "0" even for input like n=99.

Is there anyway other than having a loop which multilplies the output by 2 every time and finding the modulo every time (this is not I am looking for as this will be very slow for large numbers).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long gaps,total;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>gaps;
        total=(unsigned long long)powf(2,gaps)%1000000007;
        cout<<total<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was asked two days ago.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231366/c-c-large-number-calculation  Contest?  Homework?

Comment: yes yes ...it worked !! Thanks people for helping.I love this site.

Answer (score 3):

> this is not I am looking for as this will be very slow for large numbers

Using a bigint library will be considerably slower pretty much any other solution.

Don't take the modulo every pass through the loop: rather, only take it when the output grows bigger than the modulus, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int modulus = 1000000007;
    int n = 88888888;
    long res = 1;
    for(long i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        res *= 2;
        if(res > modulus)
            res %= modulus;
    }
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```

This is actually pretty quick:

```
$ time ./t
./t  1.19s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 1.197 total
```

I should mention that the reason this works is that if *a* and *b* are equivalent mod *m* (that is, *a % m = b % m*), then this equality holds multiple *k* of *a* and *b* (that is, the foregoing equality implies *(a*k)%m = (b*k)%m*).

Comment: The problem i am working on has the time limit of 1 sec.Thanks for helping but as I mentioned looping n times is not the solution i am looking for ,for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You need a "big num" library, it is not clear what platform you are on, but start here:
http://gmplib.org/

Comment: Its a contest problem that i am solving,and i am not allowed to use this library.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*Chris* proposed GMP, but if you need just that and want to do things The C++ Way, not The C Way, and without unnecessary complexity, you may just want to check [this](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) out - it generates few warnings when compiling, but is quite simple and Just Works™.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your `2^n` into chunks of `2^m`.  You need to find: `

```
2^m * 2^m * ... 2^(less than m)
```

Number `m` should be `31` is for 32-bit CPU.  Then your answer is:

```
chunk1 % k  * chunk2 * k ...    where k=1000000007
```

You are still `O(N)`.  But then you can utilize the fact that all `chunk % k`  are equal except last one and you can make it `O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function. It is very inefficient but it works with very large numbers. It uses my self-made algorithm to store big numbers in arrays using a decimal like system.

mpfr2.cpp

```
#include "mpfr2.h"

void mpfr2::mpfr::setNumber(std::string a) {
    for (int i = a.length() - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; ++j, --i) {
        _a[j] = a[i] - '0';
    }
    res_size = a.length();
}

int mpfr2::mpfr::multiply(mpfr& a, mpfr b)
{
    mpfr ans = mpfr();
    // One by one multiply n with individual digits of res[] 
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < b.res_size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.res_size; ++j) {
            ans._a[i + j] += b._a[i] * a._a[j];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < a.res_size + b.res_size; i++)
    {
        int tmp = ans._a[i] / 10;
        ans._a[i] = ans._a[i] % 10;
        ans._a[i + 1] = ans._a[i + 1] + tmp;
    }
    for (i = a.res_size + b.res_size; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (ans._a[i] > 0) break;
    }
    ans.res_size = i+1;
    a = ans;
    return a.res_size;
}

mpfr2::mpfr mpfr2::mpfr::pow(mpfr a, mpfr b) {
    mpfr t = a;
    std::string bStr = "";
    for (int i = b.res_size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        bStr += std::to_string(b._a[i]);
    }

    int i = 1;
    while (!0) {
        if (bStr == std::to_string(i)) break;
        a.res_size = multiply(a, t);

        // Debugging
        std::cout << "\npow() iteration " << i << std::endl;
        ++i;
    }
    return a;
}
```

mpfr2.h

```
#pragma once
//#infdef MPFR2_H
//#define MPFR2_H
// C standard includes
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define MAX 0x7fffffff/32/4 // 2147483647
namespace mpfr2 {
    class mpfr
    {
    public:
        int _a[MAX];
        int res_size;
        void setNumber(std::string);
        static int multiply(mpfr&, mpfr);
        static mpfr pow(mpfr, mpfr);
    };
}
//#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
// Local headers
#include "mpfr2.h" // Defines local mpfr algorithm library
// Namespaces
namespace m = mpfr2;     // Reduce the typing a bit later...

m::mpfr tetration(m::mpfr, int);

int main() {
// Hardcoded tests
    int x = 7;
    std::ofstream f("out.txt");
    m::mpfr t;
    for(int b=1; b<x;b++) {
        std::cout << "2^^" << b << std::endl; // Hardcoded message
        t.setNumber("2");
        m::mpfr res = tetration(t, b);
        
        for (int i = res.res_size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            std::cout << res._a[i];
            f << res._a[i];
        }
        f << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    char c; std::cin.ignore(); std::cin >> c;
    return 0;
}

m::mpfr tetration(m::mpfr a, int b)
{
    m::mpfr tmp = a;
    if (b <= 0) return m::mpfr();
    for (; b > 1; b--) tmp = m::mpfr::pow(a, tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

I created this for tetration and eventually hyperoperations. When the numbers get really big it can take ages to calculate and a lot of memory. The `#define MAX 0x7fffffff/32/4` is the number of decimals one number can have. I might make another algorithm later to combine multiple of these arrays into one number. On my system the max array length is 0x7fffffff aka 2147486347 aka 2^31-1 aka int32_max (which is usually the standard int size) so I had to divide int32_max by 32 to make the creation of this array possible. I also divided it by 4 to reduce memory usage in the `multiply()` function.

- Jubiman